# How to add a class to the first item in foreach in cshtml

Tags: razor

```
 @foreach (var slider in Sliders)
 {
  <div class="item">
  ...
  </div>
 }
```

I am making a carousel with cshtml.
How can I assign class "active" only to the first element in Sliders?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way:

```
@{ Boolean first = true; }    
@foreach( var slider in Sliders ) {
    
    <div class="item @( first ? "active" : "" )">

    </div>

    first = false;
}
```

Another way:

```
@foreach( ( Slider s, Int32 idx ) in Sliders.Select( (s,idx) => (s,idx) ) ) {
    
    <div class="item @( index == 0 ? "active" : "" )">

    </div>
}
```

I wish C# would add "ambient variables" for `foreach` to expose the current item index without needing to use `.Select( ( item, index ) => ... )`.

Comment: Thank you! This is a really smart solution :)